# How to set value of paper-dropdown-menu with Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I am trying to set the value of a `paper-dropdown-menu` in Polymer, but am having issues.

The `paper-item` value does not match its `innerHTML`, so when trying to set it with Javascript, it displays a number instead of a name.

The code below sets the item correctly by id, but I would like to set by name instead:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu id="contact">
  <paper-listbox id="contactList"
    attr-for-selected="value"
    slot="dropdown-content">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[contacts]]">
      <paper-item value$="[[item.idContact]]">[[item.nameContact]]</paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

...

```
_updateDom() {
  let cart = localStorage.getItem('idContact');
  this.$.contact.value = cart.idContact;
}
```

How can I set the `dropdown/listbox/item` so it shows the display name?

Comment: You closed your question too soon.  Here is a solution  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a21dd41919d5d38a48bb3bde94378079

Comment: @JohnCappelletti It is now re-opened...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57514852/how-to-select-sql-server-table-as-tab-delimited-string Trying to fit the logic into a user defined function...

Comment: Are you passing a row or the entire table?

Comment: Entire tables (some tables have 1 row).

Comment: Got it ... one moment

Comment: Added a solution as a function

Answer (score 0):

Give `id` to `paper-item`, instead value

```
<paper-item id$="[[item.idContact]]">[[item.nameContact]]</paper-item>
```

and call the item with:

```
_updateDom() {
  // If you have saved the object to localStorage, you may only save as String. 
  // So need to return to Object with `JSON.parse`. 
  // And you need to save object to localStorage with JSON.stringify(obj);
  let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('idContact'));
  this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#'+ cart.idContact).innnerHTML = cart.nameContact;

}
```