# How to select SQL Server table as tab delimited string

Tags: sql-server, string

I'd like to to select a table from SQL and turn it into preferably tab delimited, otherwise CSV format.

```
| col_1 | col_2 | col_3 | col_n | 
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | 
| data5 | data6 | data7 | data8 |
```

Using `for xml path` I can get select the table as string with `<tag-name>` delimiters.

```
let str = stuff((select * from db_name for xml path('')), 1, 1 '')
```

**Actual output**

```
<col_1>data1</col_1><col_2>data2</col_2><col_3>data3</col_3><col_4>data4</col_4>
<col_5>data5</col_5><col_6>data6</col_6><col_7>data7</col_7><col_8>data8</col_8>
```

**Expected string output**

```
data1   data2    data3    data4 
data5   data6    data7    data8
```

The table is very wide, so using a method like `concat` and listing each column isn't very maintainable.

How could I select the above table as a tab delimited string?

Comment: for all of the data you could simply use `concat` or `select col_1 + '|' + col_2` and so on. I'd union that with the column names from sys.columns or something. Or, use [bcp](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1633/simple-way-to-export-sql-server-data-to-text-files/) with `queryout`. That's an easy solution. Or, change your [results to text](https://mssqltrek.com/2012/07/24/obtaining-pipe-delimited-results-from-sql-server-using-ssms/) delimiter to pipe

Comment: Is there a way to not have to declare each column? The actual table is very wide.

Comment: Yes, change your results to text delimiter in SSMS. and just dump it

Comment: Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Click that link in my first comment... https://mssqltrek.com/2012/07/24/obtaining-pipe-delimited-results-from-sql-server-using-ssms/

Comment: I'm already using `bcp` with `queryout` to write text files. I am hoping to assign this string to a variable to write a redundant copy back to SQL for logging.

Comment: You're going to cram all of your data into a single string for logging? I can't support this decision.

Comment: Yes, they mirror staging tables. Saved in this format it would be trivial to recreate the failed import files that they represent.

Comment: So why not make a backup copy of the file instead of backing up the file's contents in a column in a table in a database?

Comment: This is an [XY Problem / Question](http://xyproblem.info/) to me where I think your design is wrong. Just my opinion.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the files get consumed once imported. It's much easier to query SQL to find errors than a file system / document data store.

Comment: And these import files have associated metadata that is simpler to store in SQL.

Comment: Also, it's much simpler to recreate the import files with `bcp` in SQL that it would be to copy and paste from a file system store.

Comment: /shrug ok, I'm all for storing metadata about a file in the database, I just feel like the file itself doesn't belong there (mostly because of how much more expensive SQL Server space is, and how this will add to your backup/recovery time), and that if you can generate a file in one place (for some app to consume), you can generate a copy of that file in another place (to serve as a backup) and store metadata (like the path) for the backup file, too. Certainly don't let logic interfere with a choice you've already made, though.

Comment: Let's say `bcp` fails because an input isn't properly sanitized and the file can't be written out because there is an invalid character in the file name. What's the recovery plan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the **_RN** is required in the supplying query.  Could also be a TVF

Also, the `,ELEMENTS XSINIL` is required to keep the "position" of null values, but they will NOT be null, bur rather an empty string

**Example [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c2fe79323dde7062527079a795b6bc4e)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([col_1] varchar(50),[col_2] varchar(50),[col_3] varchar(50),[col_n] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('data1','data2','data3','data4')
,('data5','data6','data7','data8')

Select [dbo].[svf-str-Data-Tab-delimited]((Select *,_RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) From @YourTable for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL ))
```

**Returns**

```
data1    data2   data3   data4   
data5    data6   data7   data8
```

The Function if Interested

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[svf-str-Data-Tab-delimited] (@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
Begin
    Declare @S varchar(max) = ''
    Select @S = @S+ case when ColItem<>'_RN' then ColValue else '' end + case when ColItem='_RN' then char(13)+char(10) else char(9) end
     From (
            Select ColSeq   = row_number() over(order by (select null))
                  ,ColItem  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
                  ,ColValue = xAttr.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
             From  @XML.nodes('/row/*') xNode(xAttr)
          ) A
     Order By ColSeq
    Return @S
End
```

> **EDIT -**

The original solution had a trailing tab.  I also modified the function by adding parameters for the delimiter and EOL.

**Example [Updated dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=575c5724ab5445912cc563fc5154cc07)**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([col_1] varchar(50),[col_2] varchar(50),[col_3] varchar(50),[col_n] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('data1','data2','data3','data4')
,('data5','data6','data7','data8')

Declare @XML xml = (Select *,_RN=Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null)) From @YourTable for XML RAW,ELEMENTS XSINIL )

Select [dbo].[svf-str-Data-To-Delimited](char(9),char(13)+char(10),@XML)
```

**Returns**

```
data1   data2   data3   data4
data5   data6   data7   data8
```

**The Update Function**

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[svf-str-Data-To-Delimited] (@Delim varchar(50),@EOL varchar(50),@XML xml)
Returns varchar(max)
Begin

Return(
        Select convert(varchar(max),(
            Select case when Item='_RN' then ''
                        else case when nullif(lead(Item,1) over (Order by Seq),'_RN') is not null  
                             then concat(Value,@Delim)
                             else concat(Value,@EOL)
                        end 
                    end
             From (
                    Select Seq   = row_number() over(order by (select null))
                          ,Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)')
                          ,Value = xAttr.value('.','nvarchar(max)')
                     From  @XML.nodes('/row/*') xNode(xAttr)
                   ) A
             Order By Seq
             For XML Path (''),TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') )
)

End
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you John!!

Comment: @Matthew Happy to help

Comment: @Matthew Was thinking about this last night, and I made some updates if interested.  See EDIT